# Where is the string stored after sys_read?

Tags: assembly, system-calls

I'm learning assembly language with AT&T syntax and I want to read some string from the terminal, to work with it later on. 
Therefor I want to use systemcall read, but I don't know where the string is stored afterwards. Could anybody tell me how to find the string ?

Comment: May we see your code? Click "edit" below your question, paste your code, and save the question.

Comment: Usually before making the syscall you have to put into *ECX* or *RSI* (Depending on the platform) a pointer to the buffer where the string will be written to.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Answer (score 1):

It's stored in the buffer pointed to by [the 2nd arg you passed to `read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).

As Margaret Bloom comments, x86-64 Linux passes the 2nd `syscall` arg in `rsi`, while i386 Linux passes the 2nd `int 0x80` arg in `ecx`.  For more details, see the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki's section on system calls / ABIs.

---

If you pass an invalid pointer, `read` will return `-EFAULT` in `eax` and not store anything anywhere.  (You *don't* get a segfault from passing bad pointers to system calls).

Run your program under strace (`strace ./a.out`) to see all the system calls your code makes.